# Reading input value always returns undefined ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

When trying to read the input value it will always say undefined no matter what even if I do it in the console itself.

this is my code:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div onLoad={Startup()}>
                <input onKeyUp={CheckInput} id={"messageinput"} placeholder={"Bericht verzenden..."}
                       className={"messageinput"}/>
                <img className={"messageinputoption"} src={require('./Images/defaultPF.png')}/>
                <img className={"messageinputoption"} src={require('./Images/defaultPF.png')}/>
                <img className={"messageinputoption"} src={require('./Images/defaultPF.png')}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Server;

function CheckInput(event) {
    const input = document.getElementById("messageinput");

    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        if (IsCommand(input.value)) {
            let command = CheckCommand(input.value.substring(1, input.value.indexOf(" ")), input.value.substring(input.value.indexOf(" ") + 1));
        } else {
            SendMessage(input.value);
        }

        input.value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't query the DOM, use Refs instead, thats why you using React.

Comment: As far as I know, key events are triggered _before_ any text is actually written into the input therefore the value of your input is still undefined when you try to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to replicate your problem with `getElementById`, but I suggest you use `currentTarget` to fetch the `Element`, thus making the `CheckInput` function more reusable. Just change the input variable declaration to:

```
const input = event.currentTarget;
```

Or, even better, rework your input to a controlled input. See https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html.